# What would be the optimal model for continous data across 5 time points?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, mean

We are searching for the best model to represent continuous data of gene expression logFC (Y-axis) across 5 time points (X-axis), where the trend line would follow the mean expression on each day. Additionally, in each day there are two groups of genes: leading edge and the rest.
We have fitted a polynomial model or plotted the mean trend line, each with their own advantages.
The mean does not represent the flow of the data, as it provides “connect the dots” sharp trend line, while the polynomial model introduces artificial trend curves in places where there are no data points.
What would be the most statistically accurate model to represent this type of data?

the figs show the polynoomial/mean/both together

[image]

[image]

[image]

R code to generate the plots

for the polynomial with df=4:

```
ggplot(df_to_plot,aes(x = Timepoint, y = FC, colour = Label,fill = Label)) +
stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y~poly(x,4),level = 0.95, se =T)+
geom_point(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'black'))+     
scale_fill_manual(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'red')) +     
scale_color_manual(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'red'))+     
theme_classic()+     
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,tp))+     
xlab("Days")+     
ylab("Mean FC (log2)")+     
ggtitle(paste("Cluster",j))+     
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), text = element_text(size=20))
```

for the mean and SE:

```
ggplot(df_to_plot, aes(x = Timepoint, y = FC, colour = Label, fill = Label)) +     
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line") +     
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "ribbon", alpha = .5)+     
geom_point(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'red'))+
scale_fill_manual(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'red')) +     
scale_color_manual(name="Label", values = c("FALSE" = 'grey', "TRUE" = 'red'))+     
theme_classic()+     
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,tp))+     
xlab("Days")+     
ylab("Mean FC (log2)")+     
ggtitle(paste("Cluster",j))+     
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), text = element_text(size=20))
```

Comment: I’d try to fit splines or polynomial regression and perhaps try to estimate the order of the polynomial from data. Furthermore, since the two groups have roughly comparable conditional variance, I’d fit a single lm with interactions, instead of fitting separate models to the two groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those awkward situations where there isn't really a good solution other than getting more data. The nonlinear pattern might be real or might be noise - gene expression is notoriously variable, after all. Even if the nonlinearity is real, there's insufficient data (too few time points, mainly) and probably insufficient process knowledge to describe it well mathematically.

I'd be inclined to use a version of the middle plot because I think the jaggedness conveys more clearly that it is a visual aid and doesn't imply that it is capturing a real process. I think the smoothing is defensible but many readers tend to overinterpret smooth curves, which is why I'd avoid it. I would also not use the confidence bands, because I think they signal a degree of certainty that is unjustified. Or in other words, there are large and I believe implausible assumptions in their estimation.

Comment: Thank you @mkt for your thoughtful answer! I competely agree with that. It is what I had in mind, I think we'll go with the graph depecting the mean.